# What am I doing wrong that result in a graph indicating better gradients in non-scaled dot-product attention compared to the scaled version?

Tags: transformer, backpropagation, pytorch, attention, gradient

I'm trying to visualize how the gradients change as we're increasing $d_{k}$ in the scaled dot-product attention and compare it to its non scaled version but I'm failing to produce a reasonable graph that transcribes the theory. The authors of the [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) paper explain that non scaling the dot-product leads to having large values which pushes the softmax into regions where its gradients are small, which is understandable because the values inside the softmax have such a high variance around a mean of 0 that the softmax will produce a mixture of values very close to 0 and 1.

I'm trying to visualize that using the following Python code:

```
def scaled_softmax_dot_product(Q, K, scale):
    attention_logits = torch.matmul(Q, K.T)
    attention_logits /= scale
    return F.softmax(attention_logits, dim=-1)

mean_grads_with_scaling = []
mean_grads_without_scaling = []
dk_values = range(1, 321)

for d_k in dk_values:
    Q = torch.randn(16, d_k, requires_grad=True)
    K = torch.randn(16, d_k, requires_grad=True)

    # Compute attention with scaling
    output_scaled = scaled_softmax_dot_product(Q, K, scale=torch.sqrt(torch.tensor(d_k, dtype=torch.float)))
    output_scaled.backward(torch.ones_like(output_scaled))
    grad_with_scaling = Q.grad.mean().item()
    Q.grad.zero_()
    K.grad.zero_()

    # Compute attention without scaling
    output_unscaled = scaled_softmax_dot_product(Q, K, scale=1.0)
    output_unscaled.backward(torch.ones_like(output_unscaled))
    grad_without_scaling = Q.grad.mean().item()
    Q.grad.zero_()
    K.grad.zero_()

    mean_grads_with_scaling.append(grad_with_scaling)
    mean_grads_without_scaling.append(grad_without_scaling)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(dk_values, mean_grads_with_scaling, label='With Scaling', color='blue')
plt.plot(dk_values, mean_grads_without_scaling, label='Without Scaling', color='red')
plt.xlabel('Dimension of Keys (d_k)')
plt.ylabel('Mean Gradients')
plt.title('Evolution of Mean Gradients with and without Scaling')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the code I'm just computing the softmax of the non/scaled dot-product with respect to $Q$ and I was expecting the mean of the gradients for the non scaled dot-product to converge to $0$ as $d_k$ increases but that's not what the graph shows:

[image]

I'd love to understand what is the error that I'm making to for getting this graph, or if I am misunderstanding the statement.

Comment: I think is due to numerical instability. When you do `attention_logits /= scale` you should add a small constant to avoid zero division. For example with `eps = 1e-7`, you could `attention_logits /= scale + eps`.

Comment: @LucaAnzalone I added the small constant and I'm still getting the same graph. I don't think the issue is due to division by zero because that's never happening in the above code, we're either dividing by $1.0$ or $\sqrt{d_{k}} >= 1.0$